# Testing helpers which use url_for method

Tags: rspec

I have helper method something like that:

```
def my_helper(builder, name, order)
  options = {
    builder.search_key => builder.search_attributes.merge('sort' => order)
  }
  link_to name, url_for(options)
end
```

Helper adds some params (here simplified example) to current url and build link.
When I try to test this method with RSpec I get exception `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:search=>{"sort"=>"published_at.asc"}}`. How can I stub current link, path, controller, action?

Comment: did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: Sadly no. I still dont have any good trading technique for it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you only check if options got passed in as expected to `link_to` (merge the additional options correctly (`'sort' => order`)), you do not need to test `url_for`, Rails already got good test coverage for this method!